# W3 Validator errors for my website

Tags: html, css

Maybe my question will look a little weird but I spend 1 day to figure it out where is the problem and I don't get it

Here's the link of W3

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.joaca-mario.ro/

Here is the site: http://www.joaca-mario.ro/

The last 3 errors are which they interested me:

```
Line 159, Column 40: document type does not allow element "div" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag
Line 165, Column 5: end tag for "li" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
Line 159, Column 1: start tag was here
```

I don't know where is the problem but to me when I check the source code the ul and li tags looks fine. and for the last error the div pagination have a closed tag so I don't get it

Also maybe this code may help for my errors:

```
<div class="list">
<h2>Lista de jocuri recomandate - <?php if(empty($_GET) || $_GET['pg'] ==1) { echo 'Pagina 1'; } else { echo 'Pagina ' .$_GET['pg']; } ?></h2>
<ul>
<? // PHP Query + Pagination: //
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `db` ORDER BY `id` DESC"; $listLinksCount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)); if($listLinksCount > 0) { $listLinks = mysql_query($sql.$sqlLimit); $nrPagini = ceil($listLinksCount / $perpage); } if($listLinksCount > 0) { while($db = mysql_fetch_array($listLinks)) { ?>
  <li><div style="background:url(images/post.png) no-repeat; height:166px; width:197px; "><a href="/<?=$db['weblink']?>"><img src="/files/<?=$db['img']?>" class="img" width="120" height="100" title="Joaca acum <?=$db['title']?>" alt="<?=$db['title']?>" /><span class="title"><?=$db['title']?></span></a></div></li>
<? } pagination($nrPagini, $pg, '?pg=%pg'); } else { echo 'Database empty.'; } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**SOLVED:**

I hope it is correct
my new code:

```
<div class="list">
<h2>Lista de jocuri recomandate - <?php if(empty($_GET) || $_GET['pg'] ==1) { echo 'Pagina 1'; } else { echo 'Pagina ' .$_GET['pg']; } ?></h2>
<ul>
<? // PHP Query + Pagination: //
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `db` ORDER BY `id` DESC"; $listLinksCount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)); if($listLinksCount > 0) { $listLinks = mysql_query($sql.$sqlLimit); $nrPagini = ceil($listLinksCount / $perpage); } if($listLinksCount > 0) { while($db = mysql_fetch_array($listLinks)) { ?>
<li><div style="background:url(images/post.png) no-repeat; height:166px; width:197px; "><a href="/<?=$db['weblink']?>"><img src="/files/<?=$db['img']?>" class="img" width="120" height="100" title="Joaca acum <?=$db['title']?>" alt="<?=$db['title']?>" /><span class="title"><?=$db['title']?></span></a></div></li>
**<? } { ?>**
</ul>
<? } pagination($nrPagini, $pg, '?pg=%pg'); } else { echo 'Database empty.'; } ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

What I did? So I put the pagination line after the ul tag was close and I close the while statment(see `<? } { ?>` line) because if I don't close there it still continue to echo(in source code) many ul and li tags not properly. I hope what I change is correct. Now the w3 validator say everything is ok.

Comment: either you have to omit or have to study properly ....

Comment: You seem to be using HTML5 features but you haven't specified the new `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype. Instead you seem to have XHTML 1.0

Comment: @Mathias Are you confused? the new <!DOCTYPE html> doctype is for HTML5, so if he is using HTML5 then there is no problem.

Comment: Any advice? I'm very confusing, should I change my doctype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `<div id="pagination">` as a child of the `<ul>` at the end of the list. Move it outside of the `<ul>` or put it inside of its own `<li>` and it should fix the three errors.

[W3 page for `<ul>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html):

> Permitted contents Zero or more li elements

Comment: Where do you even see that div?

Comment: @Jessica He looked at the source.